# How to load sapui5 list using button?

Tags: sapui5

I have a list with three columns, ID, Operation and isOperationReleased.

On top of that, I have three buttons, "All operations", "Released operations" and "not released operations".

When I click on ***All operations*** button, list should get refreshed and should show me all operations, similarly, for ***not released operations*** and ***released operations*** it should show me respective rows in list. (Only one button will be active at a time)

Moreover, it should also show me number of rows (i.e. count) in button.

Kindly see image for more clarity

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [IconTabBar with Filters](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/samples).

[image]